# How to get out from full-screen mode

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, browser, fullscreen

I want to display my program (in winforms) in the full-screen-mode. And this is the way how I get in it:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id_string = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\astankic\ID.txt");
    int id_int = Convert.ToInt32(id_string);
    string url = @"http://z0r.de/L/z0r-de_" + id_int + ".swf";
    TopLevel = true;
    Cursor.Hide();
    webBrowser_animation.Url = new Uri();
```

In the properties of the form, I've set the FormBorderStyle to "None", the WindowState to "Maximiazed" and the TopMost to "true". The webbrowser take also the full size of the screen!

My Problem is: I want to close the program when a Key has been pressed or the mouse has been moved. I already have tried it with this etc:

```
private void Form_Screensaver_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Close();
}
```

... but it didn't worked? :-(

Comment: Have you tried ALT+F4?

Comment: I suspect the issue is that you are loading a flash file (SWF) into a WebBrowser control which is what then has the keyboard focus.  You need a way of getting the keyboard focus back to the Application.  Can we assume that your function `Form_Screensaver_KeyDown` isn't firing at all?

Comment: @ChrisWalsh Yes i have and it works, but i want to leave it when key get pressed or the mouse moved

Comment: @ChrisWalsh Your're right! the flash player control it! But do you know how to stop it anyway?

Comment: @user3347346 - Investigate the KeyPreview property of the form.  When true, you should be able to intercept the KeyDown events and react to them before they get passed on to the focused control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. First, implement the interface `IMessageFilter`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IMessageFilter
{
   ....
}
```

Next, implement the required `PreFilterMessage` method:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IMessageFilter
{
    ...

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        // If key is pressed or mouse is moved
        if (m.Msg == 0x0100 || m.Msg == 0x0200)
        {
            Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
            Application.Exit();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Next add the filter to your form's constructor and remove it when the form is closed:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
        FormClosed += Form1_FormClosed;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
    }
```

See if this works for you!

Comment: I tried it, but the program has start and short after immediately automatically closed. Mouse and keys hasn't been moved or pressed!

Comment: @user3347346 -- Try using `if (m.Msg == 0x0100)` instead. This will detect keypress only and not mouse moving.

Comment: @user3347346 -- You put the line back to what it originally was. The reason it "appears" to not be working is because of the sensitivity. You need to create some kind of threshold variable and  you need to add that variable to the `if` statement: `if (m.Msg == 0x0100 || (m.Msg == 0x0200 && threshold > 15))`

Comment: What type is the variable threshold?

Comment: Just an `int`. Create an `int` threshold and set it to 0. Then add a line above the `if` statement that says `if (m.Msg == 0x0200 && threshold<15) { threshold++; return false; }` and inside the original `if` statement, reset it back to `0`. 15 might be too low. You might have to increase it more. Experiment with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hunch but try creating another object (say a `Button`) as a sibling of `webBrowser_animation` and set the focus on that object as part of `Form_Load()`.  If pressing ENTER can fire the `Click` event of the button then you know at least that you can take the focus away from Flash.  If this works then [a] make the Button "off screen" and [b] add a generic Keyboard event handler and Mouse event handler to the form to which will do the window close.  It's all about Keyboard focus.